# Program stopped on file opening using fopen_s() based on the argc and argv command-line arguments

Tags: c++, crt

My respectful greetings to you.
the compilation of my program (written with the Visual Studio editor) is done without errors, but the execution of the .exe file stops on the opening ( with fopen_s() ) of the current file.
In the command-line, the program is called like this: <program_name_exe> <log_file(s)> <text_to_match/filter>

Eg: (in the same location of <program_name_exe>) .\program_name_exe path\to\logfiles\logfile_01.log path\to\logfiles\logfile_02.log ... path\to\logfiles\logfile_n.log abc*

01<=n<=512

the program is the following.

```
// CReader.h
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>

struct FileInfo {
    const int bufsize = 10000;
    unsigned int line_number;   // current line number.
    char* buffer;           // container of data read from file.
    FILE* file;
    fpos_t* cpos;               // current position in the file
};

class CReader{
public:
    // Default constructor.
    explicit CReader() { _argc = 0; _filter = nullptr; _argv = nullptr; _fileInfo = nullptr; }

// Constructor with arguments.
CReader(int argc, char** argv) { _argc = argc; _argv = argv; }

// Copy constructor.
CReader(const CReader& other) {
    _argc = other._argc; _filter = other._filter; _argv = other._argv; _fileInfo = other._fileInfo;
}

// Move constructor.
CReader(CReader&& other) noexcept {
    _argc = 0; delete[] _filter; delete[] _argv; delete[] _fileInfo;

    _argc = other._argc; _filter = other._filter; _argv = other._argv; _fileInfo = other._fileInfo;

    other._argc = 0; delete[] other._filter; delete[] other._argv; delete[] other._fileInfo;
}

// Copy assignment.
CReader& operator=(const CReader& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        _argc = 0; delete[] _filter; delete[] _argv; delete[] _fileInfo;

        _argc = other._argc; _filter = other._filter; _argv = other._argv; _fileInfo = other._fileInfo;
    }
    return *this;
}

// Move assignment.
CReader& operator=(CReader&& other) noexcept {
    if (this != &other) {
        _argc = 0; delete[] _filter; delete[] _argv; delete[] _fileInfo;

        _argc = other._argc; _filter = other._filter; _argv = other._argv; _fileInfo = other._fileInfo;

        other._argc = 0; delete[] other._filter; delete[] other._argv; delete[] other._fileInfo;
    }
    return *this;
}

// Function SetFilter: extract the filter string [without regular expressions] from the filter inputed to _filter.
inline bool SetFilter() {
    char* f = _argv[_argc - 1]; size_t k = 0;
    // Extraction of '*' or '?' from the filter
    for (size_t i = 0; f[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((f[i] != '*') || (f[i] != '?')) _filter[k++] = f[i]; // I have supposed that it has no '*' or '?' inside the filter. Eg: *mercy? ; ?search? ; perform* ; ....
    }
    _filter[k] = '\0';  
    // Return true if the filter is not empty.
    return (_filter != nullptr);
}

// Function GetFilter: _filter accessor.
inline char* GetFilter() { return _filter; }

// Function GetArgv: accessor of variable which contains access to arguments inputed in the command-line.
inline char** GetArgv() { return _argv; }

// Function GetArgc: accessor of the number of arguments inputed in the command-line.
inline int GetArgc() { return _argc; }

// Function GetFileInfo: accessor of structure FileInfo's pointer object.
FileInfo* GetFileInfo() { return _fileInfo; }

// Function Open: opens the current file.
inline bool Open(int i) {
    printf_s("\nFile %s opening....", _argv[i]);
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&(_fileInfo->file), _argv[i], "r");
    return (err == 0);
}

// Function GetNextLine: extracts a line [next line if it exists] from a file to the buffer.
inline bool GetNextLine(char* buf, const size_t bufsize) {
    int i = 0, ch;
    // Set the last position in the file to cpos
    if (fsetpos(_fileInfo->file, _fileInfo->cpos) == 0) {
        // Copy of a line in a buffer [buf] character by character.
        while ((ch = fgetc(_fileInfo->file)) != '\n') {
            if (i == bufsize - 1) break;
            buf[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    else fprintf_s(stderr, "Failed to set the current position in the file. ");
    // Get the last position in the file to cpos
    if (fgetpos(_fileInfo->file, _fileInfo->cpos) == 0) {
        if (ch == '\n') { _fileInfo->line_number++; }
    }
    buf[i++] = '\0';
    return ((i == bufsize) || (ch == '\n'));
    
}

// Function Close: closes the current file.
inline bool Close() { return (fclose(_fileInfo->file) == 0); }

~CReader() {
    if (_fileInfo != nullptr) {
        printf_s("\nDeleting the file(s) informations....\n");
        delete[] _fileInfo;
        printf_s("File(s) informations deleted.\n");
    }
    if (_filter != nullptr) {
        printf_s("Deleting filter....\n");
        delete[] _filter;
        printf_s("Filter deleted.\n");
    }
    if (_argv != nullptr) {
        printf_s("Deleting program arguments....\n");
        delete[] _argv;
        printf_s("Program arguments deleted.\n");
    }
}

private:
    int _argc;      // Count of the number of command-line arguments passed to the program
    char* _filter = new char[10000];    // Container of string to match
    char** _argv;   //  pointer to an array of single-byte-character or multi-byte-character strings that contain the program arguments.
    struct FileInfo* _fileInfo = nullptr;
};



// Reader.h
#pragma once
#include "CReader.h"

class Reader : public CReader{
public:
    explicit Reader();
    Reader(int argc, char* argv[]);
    Reader(const CReader& other);
    Reader(CReader&& other);

    /*Regular Expression*/

    // Function Equal: verify if the current line [buffer] and the string to match [objToMatch] are equal.
    inline bool Equal(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch);
    
    // Function EqualAt: verify if the current line [buffer] and the string to match [objToMatch] are equal at specified range of positions.
    inline bool EqualAt(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch, size_t bPos, size_t ePos);

    // Function BeginWith: verify if arg1 begins with arg2, return true if yes or false if not
    inline bool BeginWith(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch);

    // Function EndWith: verify if arg1 ends with arg2, return true if yes or false if not
    inline bool EndWith(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch);

    // Function Contain: verify if the current line [buffer] contains the string to match.
    inline bool Contain(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch);

    // Function PrintLine: Print matched line.
    inline void PrintLine();

    // Function IdentifyFilter: Performs filter identification. Return true if the filter begins or ends with '?' or '*'
    inline bool IdentifyFilter(size_t& i, size_t& inter, size_t& aster, const char* filter, size_t filterLength);
    
    // Function Find: finds the line(s) which respect(s) the regular expression.
    inline void Find();
    
    // Function Compare: compares two words and return zero if they are the same.
    inline int Compare(const void* arg1, const void* arg2);

    // Function main: contains all the processes used to handle the file(s)  
    

};



// Reader.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Reader.h"


Reader::Reader() : CReader() {}

Reader::Reader(int argc, char* argv[]) : CReader(argc, argv) {}

Reader::Reader(const CReader& other) : CReader(other) {}

Reader::Reader(CReader&& other) : CReader(other) {}

inline bool Reader::Equal(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch){ return EqualAt(buffer, objToMatch, 0, strlen(objToMatch)); }

inline bool Reader::EqualAt(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch, size_t bPos, size_t ePos){
    int cpt = 0, find = 0;
    if (Contain(buffer, objToMatch)) {
        for (size_t i = bPos; i <= ePos; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == objToMatch[cpt]) { find++; }
            cpt++;
        }
    }
    return (find == (strlen(objToMatch) - 1)); // return true if find value is equal to objToMatch's length-1.
}

inline bool Reader::BeginWith(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch){
    size_t bufLength = strlen(buffer), objLength = strlen(objToMatch);
    char* word = nullptr;
    if (objLength <= bufLength) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= (objLength - 1); i++) { word[i] = buffer[i]; }
    }
    return (Compare(word, objToMatch) == 0);
}

inline bool Reader::EndWith(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch){
    size_t bufLength = strlen(buffer), objLength = strlen(objToMatch);
    char* word = nullptr; size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = (bufLength - objLength - 1); i <= (bufLength - 1); i++) {
        word[k++] = buffer[i];
    }
    return (Compare(word, objToMatch) == 0);
}

inline bool Reader::Contain(const char* buffer, const char* objToMatch){
    char* word = nullptr; size_t cpt = 0; bool response = false;
    size_t bufLength = strlen(buffer), objLength = strlen(objToMatch);
    // Let's browse the buffer to search the objectToMatch's first character.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bufLength; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == objToMatch[cpt]) {
            // if fund, assign it to the variable word and other characters up to it position to the limited position [objLength + i - 1]
            for (size_t j = i; j < (objLength + i); j++) {
                word[cpt] = buffer[j]; cpt++;
            }
            // if word and objToMatch values are the same, leave the loop.
            if (response = (strcmp(word, objToMatch) == 0) == true) break;
            // i remember to reinitialize cpt to avoid bad assignment if the above condition is not respected.
            cpt = 0;

        }
    }
    return response;
}

inline void Reader::PrintLine(){ printf_s("Line %i: %s", GetFileInfo()->line_number, GetFileInfo()->buffer); }

inline bool Reader::IdentifyFilter(size_t& i, size_t& inter, size_t& aster, const char* filter, size_t filterLength){
    if (i < filterLength) {
        if (filter[i] == '?') { inter++; i++; IdentifyFilter(i, inter, aster, filter, filterLength); }
        if (filter[i] == '*') { aster++; i++; IdentifyFilter(i, inter, aster, filter, filterLength); }
    }
    return (((aster, inter) != (0, 0)) && (aster != inter));
}

inline void Reader::Find(){
    while (!feof(GetFileInfo()->file)) {
        if (GetNextLine(GetFileInfo()->buffer, GetFileInfo()->bufsize)) {
            char* buffer = GetFileInfo()->buffer;
            char* filter = GetFilter();

            /* Verify if the buffer contains the filter */
            if (Contain(buffer, filter)) {

                /*Verify if the last component of _argv {_argv[_argc-1]} and buffer begin with filter.*/
                if (BeginWith(GetArgv()[GetArgc() - 1], filter)
                    && BeginWith(buffer, filter)) {

                    /* Verify if _argv[_argc - 1] and buffer end with filter : buffer == filter */
                    if (EndWith(GetArgv()[GetArgc() - 1], filter)
                        && EndWith(buffer, filter)) PrintLine();

                    // _argv[_argc - 1] identification
                    size_t filterLength = strlen(filter), bufLength = strlen(buffer);
                    size_t i = filterLength; size_t aster = 0; size_t inter = 0; char* filterInputed = (GetArgv()[GetArgc() - 1]); size_t filterInputedLength = strlen(filterInputed);
                    /* Verify if _argv[_argc - 1] <filterInputed> ends with '?', '???...???' or '*', '*...***' [='*?...?*'='?*...?'], ....  */
                    if (IdentifyFilter(i, inter, aster, filterInputed, filterInputedLength)) {

                        // if <filterInputed> ends with '?': [(nInter > 0)&&(nAster == 0)], 
                        //      and if <buffer and filter> are equals within specified positions; 
                        //      the case is satisfied: '<filter>?', '<filter>??', '<filter>???', ..., '<filter>???...?'
                        // 
                        //      begining position [bPos] : the supposed begining of the filter inside the buffer according to it length.
                        //      ending position [ePos] : the position before the last [additional] character.
                        if ((inter > 0) && (aster == 0)
                            && (EqualAt(buffer, filter, (bufLength - filterLength - inter - 1), (bufLength - inter - 1)))) PrintLine();

                        // if <filterInputed> ends with '*': [(nAster > 0) && (nInter == 0)], 
                        //      if the buffer contains the filter and if the buffer does not end with the filter; 
                        //      the case is satisfied: {'<filter>*', '<filter>**', '<filter>***', ..., '<filter>***...*'} == '<filter>*'
                        //      Note: '<filter><additional-character>' matches are included in '<filter>*' matches.
                        if ((aster > 0) && (inter == 0)
                            && (Contain(buffer, filter) && (EndWith(buffer, filter) == false))) PrintLine();

                        // if <filterInputed> ends with a combinaison of '?' and '*' ['?*', '*?', '??*', ....]: [(nAster > 0) && (nInter > 0)]
                        //      if the buffer contains the filter and if the buffer does not end with the filter; 
                        //      the case is satisfied: {'<filter>?*', '<filter>*?', '<filter>*?*', ..., '<filter>**?...*?*...?'} == {'<filter>*?', '<filter>?*'}
                        if ((aster > 0) && (inter > 0)
                            && (Contain(buffer, filter) && (EndWith(buffer, filter) == false))) PrintLine();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

inline int Reader::Compare(const void* arg1, const void* arg2){
    return (_stricmp(*(char**)arg1, *(char**)arg2));
}

/* ########################## The function main ##################### */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf_s("\n########################## PROGRAM LogReader #####################");
    int response = 0;
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf_s(stderr, "\nUsage: %s <filename(s)> <text> ", argv[0]);
        response = -2;
    }
    else {
        Reader logreader(argc, argv);
        printf_s("\nFilter '%s' setting....", argv[argc - 1]);
        if (logreader.SetFilter() != false) {
            printf_s("\nFilter '%s' setted.", argv[argc - 1]);
            int i = 0;
            do{
                i++; bool open = logreader.Open(i);
                if (open == true) {
                    printf_s("\nFile %s opened.", argv[i]);
                    while (logreader.GetNextLine(logreader.GetFileInfo()->buffer, logreader.GetFileInfo()->bufsize)) {
                        logreader.Find(); delete[] logreader.GetFileInfo()->buffer;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    fprintf_s(stderr, "Failed to open the file %s .\n", argv[i]); response++;
                }
            } while (i <= (argc - 2));
        } else printf_s("Failed to set the filter %s .\n", argv[argc - 1]);
    }


    return response;
}
```

Please, help me.

Comment: You probably need to obtain an ide with a debugger or a standalone debugger and step through your code line by line looking at the variables and flow after each statement is executed. I say this because you did not appear to use a debugger and your code is far too long for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I have used visual studio debugger. when I finished writing the code, it didn't contain any errors.  I checked the code line by line and then compiled it (still with visual studio), the compilation is done without error. Only, at runtime, the code stops on the opening of the current file (the first file: argv[1]).

Comment: When you stepped through the code line by line in your debugger where did the codes execution deviate from your expectation? Did the variables look as you expected when the code deviated?

Comment: ***when I finished writing the code, it didn't contain any errors.*** Not containing errors is somewhat meaningless. You can't run code if it did contain errors. Also a compiler has no way to know if you have logical problems in your code.

Comment: `errno_t err = fopen_s(&(_fileInfo->file), _argv[i], "r");` If it stops on this line why don't you add a breakpoint and inspect the variables to see which variables don't make sense? Does it crash on this line? If it does what did the debugger tell you about the crash? In Visual Studio (not VSCode  which is a different product) I would expect it to stop on the line with the problem and tell you "Access violation" or some other error.

Comment: fopen_s() does not open the file. it has no problem with variables, I was thinking about opening mode but when i have changed it, the same problem exists

Comment: Please, would you like to compile and run it? Maybe that would help us. I did everything you suggested except using another editor or debugger as I am obligated to use visual studio.